# How is this first order differential equation linear?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook says the following:

> A first-order linear differential equation is an equation of the form $$\ dy/dx + P(x)y = Q(x)\ $$
>   where P and Q are continuous functions of x. This first-order linear differential equation is said to be in standard form.

However, in the example following this definition it solves the equation $\ xy’ - 2y = x^2 \ $ by multiplying both sides by $\ 1/x \ $, which makes $\ P(x)=2/x \ $. Doesn’t this mean $\ P(x) \ $ isn’t a continuous function in that specific case, or can we ignore this for some reason?

Thank you!

Comment: This is actually a very good question. In your example $x=0$ is a singular point of the ODE, so a solution can only exist in $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$. In each case, $P(x)$ is continuous in the domain of the solution